# How to limit the number of terms in WordPress custom taxonomy terms page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm creating theme for movies and TV series. So I have CPT named 'series' and custom Taxonomy named 'shoof_series' and custom terms(categories) for each series. when I created page template to display all terms (series) named (all-series.php) its works fine. but when trying to set how many terms to display ('posts_per_page' = 5) still display all terms in the page.

I have tried this cod.

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $terms = get_terms( 'shoof_series' ); 
    foreach( $terms as $term ) :
        $query = new WP_Query(
           array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'paged' => $paged,
              'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'shoof_series',
                       'terms' => $term->slug,
                       'field' => 'slug',
                       'hide_empty' => false, // default: true
                   )
              )
           )
        );
        if( $query->have_posts() ):
            while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
              ?>

           <div class="col">
            //my codes 
           </div>

  <?php endwhile;  endif; endforeach; ?> 

<?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

and tried this one too

```
         <?php
          $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $terms = get_terms( array(
              'taxonomy' => 'shoof_series',
              'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );

            if ( empty( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
              return;
            }

            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
              ?>

               <div class="col">
                 //my codes 
               </div>

           <?php $term->count;  }?> 

<?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

both of codes work fine, but I cant set how many posts to display per page.
so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WordPress 4.5+ you need to pass your custom taxonomy in an array… You can use [the following arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Term_Query/__construct/) in a `WP_Term_Query`.

To restrict the number of terms, use the `number` argument.

So you can replace in your code:

```php
$terms = get_terms( 'shoof_series' );
```

with the following:

```php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
    'number'   => 5, // Here set the desired number of terms
) );
```

Comment: that's worked nice. thank you. one more question, how to pages and use (pagination). when I set 'number'   => 5 it should display pagination to the second page

Comment: You could try to use the `offset` argument in conjunction with `number`argument. But as you are querying CPT posts for each term and already using pagination for them, it's going to be complicated to use a combined pagination…

Comment: can you please show me how? you can remove the pagination

Comment: @MohamedOmar You should better ask a new question, providing your own code attempt (even if it doesn't work) with details and explaining things in a clear way. It's not really possible to understand and answer via comments, and not viable for future readers. Then notify me here.